# error with keras inceptionV3 "base_model.get_layer('custom')" ValueError: No such layer: custom

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, classification

I am trying to extract features using inceptionV3 pre-trained model (comes in keras-application). My code has following chunk:

```
 base_model = InceptionV3(include_top=include_top, weights=weights, input_tensor=Input(shape=(299,299,3)))
 model = Model(input=base_model.input, output=base_model.get_layer('custom').output)
 image_size = (299, 299)
```

when I run this it gives following error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-fa1f85b62b84> in <module>()
     20 elif model_name == "inceptionv3":
     21   base_model = InceptionV3(include_top=include_top, weights=weights, input_tensor=Input(shape=(299,299,3)))
---> 22   model = Model(input=base_model.input, output=base_model.get_layer('custom').output)
     23   image_size = (299, 299)
     24 elif model_name == "inceptionresnetv2":

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py in get_layer(self, name, index)
    362         """Retrieves the model's updates.
    363 
--> 364         Will only include updates that are either
    365         unconditional, or conditional on inputs to this model
    366         (e.g. will not include updates that depend on tensors

ValueError: No such layer: custom
```

I have tried uninstalled and reinstalled Keras completely. 
Also somewhere I read to include following in inceptionV3.py file(in keras application folder):

```
from ..layers import Flatten
```

i added this in imports. Still no luck. Can anyone please help me on this? I am new to Keras.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: @DanielMöller ->The pre-trained models are loaded from the application module of Keras library and the model is constructed based on the user specified configurations in the conf.json file. After that, features are extracted from the user-specified layer in the model pre-trained with ImageNet dataset. These features along with its labels are stored locally using HDF5 file format. Also, the model and the weights are saved just to show that these could also be done in Keras. This is what i am trying to achieve.

Comment: `InceptionV2` is a prebuilt model that is built by Keras in a strict way. There isn't a conf.json, and there isn't a 'custom' layer in the model.

Comment: @DanielMöller- as specified in the comment above conf.json is user specified. Thanks for tte information on custom. I have seen few codes by people having 'custom' when they use it for InceptionResNetV2, inceptionV3 and MobileNet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok... I think you are following [this tutorial](https://gogul09.github.io/software/flower-recognition-deep-learning), which in my opinion was written by someone who isn't really the greatest Keras user.

The referred custom layer is created by the tutorial when they change the keras source code (**please don't do this, this is not a safe way of working and will create trouble in your future projects**)

The custom layer is created in this part of the tutorial:

```
`Add in "<model>.py"


...
...
if include_top:
    # Classification block
    x = GlobalAveragePooling2D(name='avg_pool')(x)
    x = Dense(classes, activation='softmax', name='predictions')(x)
else:
    if pooling == 'avg':
        x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
    elif pooling == 'max':
        x = GlobalMaxPooling2D()(x)
    x = Flatten(name='custom')(x)
...
```

Comments:

- This is totally unnecessary. Outputs from global poolings are already flattened.
- This is dangerous to your future projects since you're changing keras source code.

You can do exactly the same without creating this flatten layer by simply taking the last layer of the model:

```
lastLayer = base_model.layers[-1]
```

Even more: if the target layer is the last, you don't need any of this. Just use the `base_model` as it is.

If you want the complete model with `Dense` layer at the end, just use `include_top=True`.

If you want a custom number of classes, tell it to the model constructor.

If you want a real intermediate layer, find the name of the layer by calling `model.summary()`.